# How to enable Entity Framework Core 5 migrations in Visual Studio Community 2019 version 8.7.4 for Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac

This question is very similar to one that's already on Stack Overflow that was asked three years ago.  Please don't redirect to the older question as three years is an eternity when it comes to Microsoft releases and now the question is asking for EF Core and not the older versions of EF.

My question is basically exactly the same: I have Visual Studio for Mac and a Xamarin Forms app and I am looking into using Entity Framework Core. But there's a problem, I would like to know how to handle migrations.

If I am working on Windows I can use the Package Manager Console.

Unfortunately there is no Package Manager Console in Visual Studio for Mac... so how do you handle things like enable-migrations, add-migration or update-database on the Mac?

Comment: There is a prototype NuGet PowerShell console for Visual Studio for Mac available as a separate extension - https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions - however, as suggested by KevinMueller the best approach is likely to use the dotnet command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are the dotnet CLI tools.
To install them, use this command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

To add a migration, execute the following in the command line:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Thanks Kevin,  quick question.  Have you used Entity Framework Core with SQLite and Xamarin.  If so I would really appreciate if you could let me know your experiences of working with this combination.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 To be honest, I've never used the Entity Framework with Xamarin before. I only ever used it in ASP.NET Core projects, together with a MySQL connector. But I think it should work pretty well with Xamarin.